# Does evil return if a person does bad deeds?

Tags: fiqh

Let me start by saying that I don't believe in karma, reincarnation and other things. I just wonder how to explain cases when a person does good/bad things and after some time it comes back to him? I heard that Allah does not punish people in this life, but only when the Day of Judgment comes. I could be wrong. Accordingly, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong as Allah may punish in this life as well, there are several verses in the Quran such as  [30:41](https://quran.com/30/41?translations=20),  [13:34](https://quran.com/13/34?translations=20).

Comment: @UmH Well, if that's the case, that's good. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to Quran the Hell is currently surronding people. not only at Judgement day.

> يَسۡتَعۡجِلُونَكَ بِٱلۡعَذَابِ وَإِنَّ جَهَنَّمَ لَمُحِيطَةُۢ
> بِٱلۡكَٰفِرِينَ
>
> They hasten/urge you with the torture, and that truly Hell is
> surrounding/enveloping (E) with the disbelievers.[(54)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/29/54/)

Please note that this is in accordance with the grammar of  the present tense in this verse.